# Writing to multiple (splitting) CSV files with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm using a simple function to write write arrays to a CSV-file, which look like this:

```
function writeToCSV($array) {
    $fp = fopen('programmes.csv', 'a');
    fputcsv($fp, $array);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Simple as a pie. However, is there anyway to know what line-number the pointer is at? Because I want to be able to after 1000 lines to begin writing to a new file. Why? Because I need to be able to import them to a database later with some memory constraints, and to parse a CSV-file with 15000 lines is a no-no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function writeToCSV($array) {
    $i = 1;
    $j = 1;
    $fp = fopen('programmes' . $j . '.csv', 'a');
    foreach($array as $fields) {
        if ($i % 1000 == 0) {
            fclose($fp);
            $fp = fopen('programmes' . $j . '.csv', 'a');
            $j = $j + 1;
        }
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Hehe, not quite as complicated as I pictured in my head =) This should work as I want it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
count(file('programmes.csv'));
```

This will give you the number of lines in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried if this works, but i would do something like this:

```
<?php
function writeToCSV($array) {
  // count lines in the current file
  $linecount = 0;
  $fh = fopen('programmes.csv','rb') or die("ERROR OPENING DATA");
  while (fgets($fh) !== false) $linecount++;
  fclose($fh);

  $aSize = sizeof($array);
  if (($linecount + $aSize) > 1000) {
    // split array
    $limit = 1000 - $linecount;
    $a = array_slice($array, 0, $limit);
    $b = array_slice($array, $limit);
    // write into first file
    $fp = fopen('programmes.csv', 'a');
    foreach($a as $field) fputcsv($fp, $field);
    fclose($fp);

    // write into second file
    $fp = fopen('programmes2.csv', 'a');
    foreach($b as $field) fputcsv($fp, $field);
    fclose($fp);
  } else {
    $fp = fopen('programmes.csv', 'a');
    $idx = 0;
    while ($linecount < 1000) {
      // fill the file to the 1000 lines
      fputcsv($fp, $array[$idx]);
      ++$linecount;
      ++$idx;
    }
    fclose($fp);

    if ($idx != $aSize) {
      // create new file
      $fp = fopen('programmes.csv', 'a');
      while ($idx< $aSize) {
        // fill the file to the 1000 lines
        fputcsv($fp, $array[$idx]);
        ++$idx;
      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
}
?>
```